# Problem java can not drag the JInternalFrame

Tags: java

I created a project with Netbeans and added a JInternalFrama graphically (from the program editor and not from the code), the component can see it and select it, but I can't move it or resize it.

Questo è il codice generato da Netbeans in the principal frame:

```
jInternalFrame2 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();

setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

jInternalFrame2.setVisible(true);

javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame2.getContentPane());
jInternalFrame2.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame2Layout);
jInternalFrame2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGap(0, 239, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);
jInternalFrame2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
    jInternalFrame2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGap(0, 126, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);

javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
layout.setHorizontalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGap(433, 433, 433)
        .addComponent(jInternalFrame2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addContainerGap(967, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);
layout.setVerticalGroup(
    layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
        .addGap(255, 255, 255)
        .addComponent(jInternalFrame2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        .addContainerGap(174, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);

pack();
```

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: From [the JInternalFrame documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html): “Generally, you add JInternalFrames to a JDesktopPane.”  Add a JDesktopPane to your content pane, and add your JInternalFrame to that JDesktopPane.

Comment: I tried putting JInternalFrame in JDesktopPane but it doesn't work anyway